# I have a problem with laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss

Tags: laravel, composer-php, tailwind-css, preset

I can't install the preset and I don't why and I tried to do it with (-W)...
but nothing changes the same problem

```
 composer require laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss:*
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss[0.1.0, ..., 0.4.2] require laravel/framework 5.5.* -> found laravel/framework[v5.5.0, ..., v5.5.50] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.8).
    - laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss 0.4.3 requires laravel/framework 5.5.*|5.6.* -> found laravel/framework[v5.5.0, ..., v5.6.40] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.8).   
    - laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss[0.5.0, ..., 0.7.1, 1.0.0, ..., 1.0.3] require laravel/framework ^5.5 -> found laravel/framework[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.38] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.8).
    - laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss[2.0.0, ..., 2.2.2, 3.0.0] require laravel/framework ^5.5 || ^6.0 -> found laravel/framework[v5.5.0, ..., v5.8.38, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.44] but it conflicts with 
your root composer.json require (^10.8).
    - laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss[4.0.0, ..., 4.2.0] require laravel/framework ^7.0 -> found laravel/framework[v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.6] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.8).
    - laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss[4.3.0, ..., 4.3.1] require laravel/framework ^8.0 -> found laravel/framework[v8.0.0, ..., v8.83.27] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.8).
    - Root composer.json requires laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss * -> satisfiable by laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss[0.1.0, ..., 0.7.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 2.0.0, ..., 2.2.2, 3.0.0, 4.0.0, ..., 4.3.1].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you running? Newer versions already ship with Tailwind

Comment: For Frontend preset for Tailwind CSS you need Laravel 7.0+

Comment: `laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss` has seen its last update in  September 2020, so it's not a surpise that it does not support current versions of Laravel

Answer (score 1):

As of today, the latest Tailwindcss requires laravel 8  while your composer requires laravel 10

> laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss[4.3.0, ..., 4.3.1] require laravel/framework ^8.0

> your root composer.json require (^10.8)

Either downgrade your laravel installation to 8 or forget about laravel-frontend-presets

Even on [their github page](https://github.com/laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss), they say it requires laravel ^7.0 and has not been updated for the past 3 years (4.3.1 Latest version, released on Sep 13, 2020)