Version conflict installing Eloquent on Laravel framework
Hello I have installed Laravel framework with Breeze starter kit, which runs on php 8.1.2. Laravel version is 10.48.10.
Unforunately, when I try to add Eloquent with
 composer require laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss -W --dev
I get a conflict :
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Laravel attempts to match versions with -W option, allowing to upgrade / downgrade some packages in order to find a working combination, but without success.
I had a look at my composer.json :
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.29",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}

But can't find what's going wrong. Can you help me figure it out ?
Thank you

Eloquent is a built-in part of Laravel. It looks like you're trying to add Tailwind CSS.

That package hasn't been updated in years, and is only compatible with Laravel 8.x. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76128317/i-have-a-problem-with-laravel-frontend-presets-tailwindcss

Ah ok, thank you, so if Eloquent is already included in Laravel, there is nothing more to install to build my own model / controller using this interface ? Especially if the package is no longer up to date right ?
